# Whats the best way to return a boolean from a function in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, function, boolean, return

I have two codes i am considering.

Which one would be the more correct way to return a boolean and why?  I will be using this function in a MVC view.

```
Function MultiplicativeIsEffective(ByVal p As someobjectpassed) As Boolean

  '1st:     
  Return Convert.ToBoolean(If(p.EffectiveDate > CDate("04/02/2015"), True, False))

  '2nd:       
  Return policy.Endorsement.EffectiveDate > CDate("04/02/2015")

End Function
```

Comment: Side point: consider using date literal syntax `#4/2/2015#` or, better yet, `new DateTime(2015, 4, 2)` rather than converting a string literal.

Comment: Something to consider: Should `MultiplicativeIsEffective()` be part of the `someobjectpassed` Class itself?  It could be read-only property instead of a function, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are both correct in that they return the correct boolean value.

The first one just has redundancies in it.

```
p.EffectiveDate > CDate("04/02/2015")
```

results in a boolean value. The following does not add any value since all it does is look at a boolean value and then return that boolean value.  So this is not doing anything.

```
If(p.EffectiveDate > CDate("04/02/2015"), True, False)
```

and finally the following is taking a boolean value and then converting it to a boolean value, which is actually not doing anything.

```
Convert.ToBoolean(If(p.EffectiveDate > CDate("04/02/2015"), True, False))
```

So the first one is doing a test that resulting in a boolean and then you twice convert that boolean into a boolean.

You want to use the second one.

Answer (score 3):

They are both syntactically correct, but the bottom one is significantly more readable and avoids unnecessary work.  The upper version converts a Boolean (`p.EffectiveDate > CDate("04/02/2015")`) to a Boolean (`True` or `False` in the `If` statement) to a Boolean (`Convert.ToBoolean`).  The extra work is pointless.